# Localization not working in my UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, multilingual, multilingual-app-toolkit

I have my UWP app in the Windows Store. I have set up multiple languages using the multilingual app toolkit But somehow localization just doesn't work. I tried multiple times by setting my display language to one of my supported language but it just doesn't work.

I have created a sample project also so that anyone could help me out.
Here is the link-https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar2Oon4jkTNAqdkRe4R6gpr6DOXRDw

Comment: Have you tried if it works on emulator? Have you tried to change language on your phone and then install the app (not after installation)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the "new" localization system based on `x:Uid` introduced in Windows 8.1 apps, please have a look at the following tutorial which gives you an example in detail: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/862152/Localization-in-Windows-Universal-Apps

Your error basically is the name in the resw-file. You have a `TextBlock` in your project like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="Hi" />
```

Then in your resw-file your translated string must have:

- The name `Hi.Text` (because you want to localize the TextProperty of the block)
- The value you want to be shown (e.g. *Hi* in English, *Hallo* in German, etc.)

This system allows you to change your UI based on a language, e.g. you can add in the German resw file only a second string with name `Hi.Foreground` and the value *Green* and the string will be green but only in German.

In your project it shows always *Hi*, because you have it as a static value:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="Hi" Text="Hi"></TextBlock>
```

If you remove `Text="Hi"` then nothing will be shown in your current project because of what I explained above.

Comment: why should you use as Hi.Text? if you want to use somewhere else on other tool not as Text Property? Should you add another Hi.Content for example?

Comment: @batmaci Yes, if you want to address a local value for the ContentProperty, you would have to set Hi.Content in that case.